# Vue: How to enable class of selected button using class binding

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Alert: Learning Vue :)

I have a list of items displayed in tables along with status button

[image: I am using this sortable table]

I tried to use the v-for but than my search and sortable options doesn't work so I am displaying data using php (laravel) So I only want my status button to work with Vue

I have so far managed to make it work but the only problem is class binding not working for clicked item and it is changing for all of the buttons

here are my html

```
<td class="center">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini">
    <i class="fa fa-fw" :class="{'fa-thumbs-o-up': form.isStatus, 'fa-thumbs-o-down': !form.isStatus }" @click="onStatus({{$row->id}})">
    </i></a>
</td>
```

here are my due codes

```
new Vue({
  el: '#viewall',

  data: {
    form: new Form({
      status: '',
      isStatus: true
    }),

    errors: new Errors()
  },

  methods: {
    onStatus(id) {
      this.form.statusUpdate('post', 'updatestatus', id)
    }
  }
})

class Form {
  constructor() {}

  // update status
  statusUpdate(requestType, url, id) {
    let data = new FormData()

    data.set('pageid', id)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios[requestType](url, data)

        .then(response => {
          this.isStatus = response.data.new_status
        })

        .catch(error => {})
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this:

> the only problem is class binding not working for clicked item and it is changing for all of the buttons

Obviously because all of your buttons depends on the same one variable `isStatus`.

You should have different `isStatus` for each button, like `isStatus_n`:

But I understand that you don't have those dynamic Vue data property because it is from Laravel.

So you can do like:

```
<td class="center">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini">
        <i class="fa fa-fw" :class="{'fa-thumbs-o-up': form.isStatus_{{$row->id}} && form.isStatus_{{$row->id}}.selected, 'fa-thumbs-o-down': !form.isStatus_{{$row->id}} }" @click="onStatus({{$row->id}})">
        </i>
    </a>
</td>
```

Then on your method:

```
// This will insert/update the form.isStatus_n
var newSet = {selected: true};
this.$set(this.form, 'isStatus_'+id, newSet);
```

Made a simple demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j9whxnfs/37/

Comment: thanks mate. Now I hit another problem. Regardless of what is the status in database. page always load up with all the button fa-thumbs-o-down class. How to solve this? I want page to load with existing status and button should change status. Also once status changed to thumb up, it's not going down.